# Webservice exception potential causes

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I am getting following exception but can't find out what is causing it. The following exception is thrown when method getSlownikiOfflinePort is invoked.

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "SlownikiOfflinePort")
    public SlownikiOffline getSlownikiOfflinePort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://gugik.gov.pl/schemas/slowniki-offline-service/1.0", "SlownikiOfflinePort"), SlownikiOffline.class);
    }
```

super class is javax.xml.ws.Service for this method is

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class pl.package.OfflineService.PobierzPelne do not have a property of the name {http://gugik.gov.pl/schemas/slowniki-offline-service/1.0}teryt
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.BodyBuilder$DocLit.<init>(BodyBuilder.java:245) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.<init>(StubHandler.java:132) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.initStubHandlers(DatabindingImpl.java:162) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:107) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:120) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:882) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:899) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:862) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:451) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:420) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:402) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:169) ~[jaxws-api.jar:na]
    at pl.package.OfflineService.getOfflinePort(SlownikiOfflineService.java:72) ~[classes/:na]  
..............................................................................................................................................................................................
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: {http://gugik.gov.pl/schemas/slowniki-offline-service/1.0}teryt is not a valid property on class pl.package.OfflineService.PobierzPelne
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:960) ~[jaxb-runtime.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextWrapper.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBRIContextWrapper.java:121) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.BodyBuilder$DocLit.<init>(BodyBuilder.java:242) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.1]
    ... 107 common frames omitted
```

For some reason {http://gugik.gov.pl/schemas/slowniki-offline-service/1.0}(address of service) is added to property name only for this one class and it is causing exception.

The problem is that this class is generated from WSDL along with other classes and for some reason is the only one causing that exception or having service address appended to it's property name. As it is exception thrown in library code I cannot handle or modify it(in debug mode deleting address from property name makes it work in Intellij code evaluation tool).

The code of class causing Exception:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "pobierzPelne", propOrder = {
    "teryt"
})
public class PobierzPelne {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String teryt;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the teryt property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTeryt() {
        return teryt;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the teryt property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTeryt(String value) {
        this.teryt = value;
    }

}
```

Here is code one of classes that do not cause exception to be thrown:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "pobierzUlice", propOrder = {
    "iipPn",
    "iipId",
    "pelna"
})
public class PobierzUlice {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "")
    protected String iipPn;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "")
    protected String iipId;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "")
    protected boolean pelna;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the iipPn property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getIipPn() {
        return iipPn;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the iipPn property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setIipPn(String value) {
        this.iipPn = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the iipId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getIipId() {
        return iipId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the iipId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setIipId(String value) {
        this.iipId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the pelna property.
     * @return value
     */
    public boolean isPelna() {
        return pelna;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the pelna property.
     * @param value value
     */
    public void setPelna(boolean value) {
        this.pelna = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you invoke this service with SOAPUi?

Comment: Yes, connection to webservice works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error was caused by absence of generated package-info.java file. Turned out that it was deleted.